# Why Displaying Error in Apollo Client in React Not Showing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

I need to display the error coming from apollo. I wonder why if I console.log it, it says `Error: undefined at new ApolloError`

```
const {
  error,
  loading,
  refetch,
  data: { findOrders: { orders } = {} } = {},
} = useQuery(FIND_ORDERS, {
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  variables: {
    fromDate: "date here",
    toDate: "date here",
  },
});

if (error) {
  console.error(error);
  return <div>Error!</div>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return <div>Error!</div>;
  }
}, [error])
```

In your example checking `error` doesn't work because object `error` isn't ready yet.

Comment: @Joseph so maybe you just don't have errors :D
Try to console just an object from the query and check if you have any response at all

Comment: Actually it has. its more on Apollo client

Comment: @Joseph I don't know now. It depends on where exactly do you run this query and so on. Imo, try to `console.log` response and figure out if you have an error on `data` or something. I can't help you know.